# Django expiring "password reset" model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's say my website will have a "reset password" button for when the user forgets his password, it will generate a link with a hash based on `url_token` field from `Password_Reset_Token` and email it to the user.

If the user access the url, the view can then reset his password and delete the `Password_Reset_Token` object.

But what if it expires and the link isn't accessed? Is there a way to add a daily task to clean expired objects?

Or is there a more clever way to do this?

*Worth nothing that my application is entirely AJAX based and has no url redirecting*

```
class Password_Reset_Token(models.Model):
    url_token = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    expiringdays = models.IntegerField(default = 12)
```

Comment: This functionality already exists built-in to Django. It creates a token that encodes the creation date, no need for a model.

Comment: @DanielRoseman do you happen to have a link for that?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset

Comment: Haha wow, how convenient

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [creating a custom command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#howto-custom-management-commands) that purges expired records. Run that periodically or via an automated process such as [cron](http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/).